# Как пишется слово "видеозвонок"?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется слово **"видеозвонок"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не удалось найти это слово в академических словарях, но оно есть в Викисловаре:

**видеозвонок**

*Значение: звонок, производимый посредством видеосвязи*

Многочисленные примеры применения можно найти в газетном корпусе (раздел Нац. корпуса русского языка)